# My iPhone 4 has just stopped charging -- what could be wrong with it?

Tags: ios

I have had this iPhone4 for about over three years now but it suddenly won't charge. It comes on at 1% and than turns straight back off and it keeps doing that whilst on the charger.
I don't even have enough time to turn off my phone.

Could someone please tell me if I need a new phone or a new battery ?
what is wrong with it it has all my contacts and details in it and I need it fixed.

Comment: In all possibility, your battery has died or the battery logic board is fried. Either way it is better to take it to the Apple store where they can run diagnostics and tell you the actual problem.

Comment: Try charging on a different charger or computer. Try a different cable. Check the port for dust and dirt. If all that doesn't help it's most likely - but not definitely - the battery.